# Issues with controller nested element's incrementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, increment

I'm trying to create a magazine which could be read online. To do so, I created a scaffold for the magazine itself, then another scaffold nested inside the first one for the pages. After this, I created a system to allow the multi upload from the magazine scaffold, that would automatically create a new entry inside the page's scaffold for each images uploaded in the same time (one image = one page).

After some tries, I figured that setting the id as the page number isn't really smart since it auto increments and won't start from 1 again. So I created a new column inside the page scaffold named "page_number", that would be set to one when the first image from the multi upload form would be uploaded / added to the pages scaffold, then the following page will get this number's incrementations.

Anyway here's my controller (the relevant part of it)

```
class MagazinesController < ApplicationController
#Some code..

  def create
    @magazine = Magazine.new(magazine_params)

    if @magazine.save
      if params[:images] #If there are images loaded in the multi upload form
        params[:images].each { |image, index| #for each of them...
          if index == 0 
            @magazine.pages.page_number = 1 #Set the first one's page_number to 1
          else
            @magazine.pages.page_number += 1 #Set its incrementation after that
          end
          #Save each of the images as a new image from the :image scaffold
           @magazine.pages.create(image: image) 
        }
      end
      redirect_to @magazine, notice: 'Magazine créé'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

#Some code..

end
```

My issue is that, even after rebooting the server once the migration done, when I try to upload a new magazine, I get the following error: `undefined method 'page_number' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

When I looked up on the web, I found two ways to increment things, via the model and an SQL request and via the controller and this method, that fits more my needs. I don't know how to solve that, since I needed to specify things in another nested element and everything went pretty well without any issues, and since RubyMine suggests this "page_number" after adding a dot after "@magazine.pages" without trouble.

What did I forget ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will rewrite your code a little bit:

```
def create
  @magazine = Magazine.new(magazine_params)

  if @magazine.save
    (params[:images] || []).each_with_index do |image, index| #for each of them...
      #Save each of the images as a new image from the :image scaffold
      @magazine.pages.create(image: image, page_number: index + 1) 
    end
    redirect_to @magazine, notice: 'Magazine créé'
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

The error you're getting is because you're trying to assign to `pages` relation the `page_number`, which is true that it doesn't exist. @magazine`.pages` is a relation not an instance, hence the relation doesn't have that(`page_number`) method defined.

What I did, is that I'm just assigning the `page_number` to the `page` instance being created in the `@magazine.pages.create...` line, and the index will be aligned with the index + 1 of the loop.

the `(params[:images] || []).each` is just to avoid having the `if` to check if the `images` param comes in the request, if doesn't come, the loop won't execute because the array will be empty(`|| []`).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your clear answer! I now get why I'm having this trouble, however, I've rewritten my code following yours, but now I have the following error: `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`, it seems that Rails still doesn't understand what "page_number" is..

Comment: sorry, that `.each` should be `.each_with_index do |image, index|`. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I was too tired to realize that it was `each_with_index`, anyway, it worked smoothly, thank you a lot, I don't think I would have find this solution on my own !!